# Preserving HTML tags inside XQuery

Tags: xquery

I'm using eXist for a project at work, and I've run into a problem that I can't seem to figure out a solution for.

I have an xquery script that is updating an existing document that is already in the database.  Part of the data that needs to be updated contains HTML, specifically `<p>` and `</p>` tags.  I cannot get eXist/XQuery to stop escaping the HTML.  It *needs* to be preserved in it's original form.  Here's a very simple version of what I'm doing:

```
<pre>
declare variable $raw-content := request:get-parameter('content', '')
declare variable $content := local:clean($raw-content)
</pre>
```

`local:clean` is the following function:

```
<pre>
declare function local:clean($text) {
     let $text := util:parse($text)
     return $text
};
</pre>
```

Later on in the code I update a specific XML element

```
<pre>
{update replace $n/sports-content/article/nitf/body/body.content with <body.content>{$content}</body.content>}
</pre>
```

Now, this works perfect *if* I only pass in data wrapped in one set of tags (ie `<p>foo</p>`).  If I do `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>`, I get a null value placed in `$text`.

I've been banging my head against the desk for a day and a half now trying to figure out why this doesn't work.  Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a problem with `util:parse` specifically, not the rest of your code (and I don't see any alternative way to do what you want here). Have you tried testing `util:parse` specifically on the sample input that you give in the question (i.e. `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>`) to verify that it does indeed not parse a multi-node fragment correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A guess: `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>` is not well-formed (no root element) while `<p>foo</p>` is well-formed (one root element).

So try `util:parse-html` instead of `util:parse`.